# Disable remote input is greyed out in TeamViewer Actions menu

Tags: remote-control, teamviewer, unattended

I'm trying to set up for unattended remote operation of an iMac and would like the remote system to remain black (as it's an all-in-one, I can't just turn off the monitor). On the local machine, in my TeamViewer Actions menu, the "Disable remote input" option is greyed out. I understand this must be selected before "Show black screen" can be selected. So I can do neither.

Remote system: Mac Free Version 10.0.47374 
Local system: Windows Free Version 10.0.47484
(up to date non-Beta versions).

Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

COPY and paste (worked for me) 
https://www.reddit.com/r/teamviewer/comments/5to1e0/unable_to_remote_control_tv12_wont_even_try_to/

""Ok, I figured it out... Under the advanced settings outbound remote control was disabled. I most certainly did NOT disable it as I haven't been in the settings for quite some time, so I'd love to know why it just randomly decided to turn it off this morning, on TWO separate systems.""

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.